# Can Bitly shorten percent symbol contained URL?

Tags: url-shortener

I have been trying to shorten URL contains % symbol to bitly shorten API:

Examples

My Original URL:

> https://www.google.com?param=40%OFF

Doesn't work

> https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=...&longUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%3Fparam%3D40%25+OFF

When I try to eliminate the percent from URL, then encoded it again, it works:

> https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=...&longUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%3Fparam%3D40+OFF

I am not able to find Bitly doc states it does not able to shorten percent contained URL

Anyone has advise?

Comment: I bet this should work fine, once you properly URL-encode this ...

Comment: @CBroe it has been properly encoded `%` to `%25` or I miss something?

Comment: Yes, the “level” of encoding we are talking about here. The value of the parameter `longUrl` of the “outer” URL has been properly encoded, but the actual value you are passing to the bitly endpoint in the first case is `https://www.google.com?param=40%OFF`, and that is _not_ a properly encoded URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you're passing to shorten isn't a syntactically valid URL. Perhaps you meant `...&longUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%3Fparam%3D40%2525OFF`, which when decoded gives `longUrl` the value `https://www.google.com?param=40%25OFF`, which when decoded gives `param` the value `40%OFF`. Without the "extra" `25`, decoding fails at the second step since `O` isn't a hexadecimal digit.

Comment: Then bitly returns this response `https://www.google.com/?param=40%25OFF` with additional `25` which not needed

Comment: _“with additional 25 which not needed”_ - it _is_ needed. You are confusing technical requirements with aesthetic ones here. Yes, `...?param=40%OFF` might have “looked nice” to the marketing department,  but that simply doesn’t make it _correct_. If you want to have a percent sign in the query string that is meant to be a percent sign, then that’s `%25` when properly encoded.

Comment: Bitly requires encoded URL to be passed inside longURL, so I think my first longURL supposed to be working.

Comment: No, because the URL you are passing for that parameter is not correct to begin with. Again: `https://www.google.com?param=40%OFF` might look more pleasing to your eye, but it is _not_ correct, correct is only `https://www.google.com?param=40%25OFF` If you used the former in HTML in a link for example, the browser will automatically fix what you neglected to do properly here, and encode this the way it is supposed to, before it sends the request. [...]

Comment: But the bitly API doesn’t care what error correction browsers might apply. Your correct URL is `https://www.google.com?param=40%25OFF`, and when you properly encode that to put it into another URL as parameter value, that becomes `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%3Fparam%3D40%2525OFF`

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thanks!!